# JQuery local variables in anonymous function lakes

Tags: javascript, jquery, lambda, jquery-animate, anonymous-function

I am not sure so I decide to ask here. I have a plugin which uses jquery animate function and then it call complete callback. It works pretty much with dom. After few cycles script starts to be slow. I cant find any issue only local lambda variables. But I dont know why this local variables should remain in memory. It does not make sense. Here is the code:

```
        cEl.el.animate( { left: offset.left - state.cEl.mL, top: offset.top - state.cEl.mT }, 250,
            function()  // complete callback
            {
                tidyCurrEl( cEl );

                targetEl.after( cEl.el[0] );
                targetEl[0].style.display = 'none';
                hintStyle.display = 'none';
                hintNode.remove();

                ......

                if ( isHintTarget )
                {
                    // This seems to be a problem.
                    var paretnLi = state.placeholderNode.parent().closest( 'li' )
                    ......
                }
                else
                {
                    ......
                }

            } );
```

Am I right the local variables in anonymous function is the problem? Thanks.

Here is full code example

```
function endDrag( e )
{
    var cEl = state.cEl,
        hintNode = $( '#s-l-hint', state.rootEl.el ),
        hintStyle = hint[0].style,
        targetEl = null, // hintNode/placeholderNode
        isHintTarget = false, // if cEl will be placed to the hintNode
        hintWrapperNode = $( '#s-l-hint-wrapper' );

    if ( hintStyle.display == 'block' && hintNode.length && state.isAllowed )
    {
        targetEl = hintNode;
        isHintTarget = true;
    }
    else
    {
        targetEl = state.placeholderNode;
        isHintTarget = false;
    }

    offset = targetEl.offset();

    cEl.el.animate( { left: offset.left - state.cEl.mL, top: offset.top - state.cEl.mT }, 250,
        function()  // complete callback
        {
            tidyCurrEl( cEl );

            targetEl.after( cEl.el[0] );
            targetEl[0].style.display = 'none';
            hintStyle.display = 'none';
            // This has to be document node, not hint as a part of documentFragment.
            hintNode.remove();

            hintWrapperNode
                .removeAttr( 'id' )
                .removeClass( setting.hintWrapperClass );

            if ( hintWrapperNode.length )
            {
                hintWrapperNode.prev( 'div' ).append( opener.clone( true ) );
            }

            var placeholderNode = state.placeholderNode;
            // Directly removed placeholder looks bad. It jumps up if the hint is below.
            if ( isHintTarget )
            {
                placeholderNode.slideUp( 150, function()
                {
                    var placeholderParent = placeholderNode.parent();
                    var placeholderParentLi = ( ! placeholderParent.is( state.rootEl.el ) ) ? placeholderParent.closest( 'li' ) : null;

                    placeholderNode.remove();
                    tidyEmptyLists();

                    setting.onChange( cEl.el );
                    setting.complete( cEl.el ); // Have to be here cause is necessary to remove placeholder before complete call.
                    state.isDragged = false;

                    if( setting.maxLevels !== false )  // Has to be after placeholder remove.
                    {
                        recountLevels( cEl.el );
                        if( placeholderParentLi ) recountLevels( placeholderParentLi );
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                state.placeholderNode.remove();
                tidyEmptyLists();
                setting.complete( cEl.el );
                state.isDragged = false;
            }

        } );

    scrollStop( state );

    state.doc
        .unbind( "mousemove", dragging )
        .unbind( "mouseup", endDrag );
}
```

Comment: Could you post a complete example?

Comment: I made an edit. There it is.

Comment: Can I include the html too?

Comment: This is the plugin http://camohub.github.io/jquery-sortable-lists/#cssPattern you can see all edits in git repository. I am pretty sure we have not enough space here.